# Sort Excel data based on the dependent value from the other column

Tags: excel, sorting

I have the below data set in excel.

[image]

Here column Next depends on column Dependent. For example, z is dependent on m in the last row.
Is it possible to sort the data to get the result as below,

[image]

Tried with sort and other methods, did not get the expected result. Is it possible to automate with any function or method?

Comment: How you sort data? It is neither ascending nor descending order? Can you explain logic to sort this. Only custom sort may work.

Comment: For a, d is dependent. For d, z is dependent. For z, m is dependent. For m, n is dependent. There is no entry in the first column for n. So m with n as dependent will be the first element. Then we can put z since the dependent m is already considered and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with pull-down formulas in another pair of columns, if that's any help. In Excel 365:

In E2

```
=FILTER(B2:B6,COUNTIF(A2:A6,B2:B6)=0)
```

In D2

```
=XLOOKUP(E2,B$2:B$6,A$2:A$6)
```

In E3

```
=D2
```

[image]

If you didn't have Excel 365, you would have to use index/match:

In H2:

```
=INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(A2:A6,B2:B6),0))
```

In G2:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$6,MATCH(H2,B$2:B$6,0))
```

In H3:

```
=G2
```

Array-entering them where necessary.